# How to load a sequence of image files using a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, imread

I am beginner in MATLAB. I would like to load 200 image files (size 192x192) in a specific folder by using a for loop.

The image names are '1.png', '2.png', '3.png' and so on.

My code is as below.

```
list = dir('C:/preds/*.png');
N = size(list,1);
sum_image = zeros(192,192,200);
for i = 1:N
    sum_image(:,:,i) = imread('C:/preds/i.png');
end
```

Which part should I change ?

Comment: Is anything in particular not working?  Getting errors anywhere, etc.  Also, are the filenames 0 padded... so 001, 002 ... 009, 010...etc.  or  1, 2, ..,9,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it like the code below:
You are currently getting the list of filenames then not really doing much with it.  Iterating over the list is safer otherwise if there is a missing number you could have issues.  Also, the sort maybe unnecessary depending if you image numbering is zero-padded so they come out in the correct order ... but better safe than sorry.  One other small change initializing the array to size `N` instead of hard-coding 200.  This will make it more flexible.

```
searchDir = 'C:\preds\';
list = dir([searchDir '*.png']);
nameList = {list.name}; %Get array of names
imNum = str2double(strrep(nameList,'.png','')); %Get image number
[~,idx] = sort(imNum); %sort it 
nameList = nameList(idx);

N = numel(nameList);
sum_image = zeros(192,192,N);
for i=1:N
    sum_image(:,:,i) = imread(fullfile(searchDir,nameList{i}));
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Comment: No problem & no need for thanks.  Just upvote if useful and downvote if not.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the line within the loop to the following:

```
sum_image(:,:,i) = imread(['C:/preds/', num2str(i), '.png']);
```

MATLAB treats the *i* in your string as a character and not the variable *i*. The above line of code builds your string piece by piece.

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't a homework problem, the right answer to this question is don't write this as a for loop. Use an imageDatastore:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagedatastore.html

```
ds = imageDatastore('C:/preds/');
sumImageCellArray = readall(ds);
sumImage = cat(3,sumImageCellArray{:});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments!